# Dataframe count of unique values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe with two columns A and B:

```
        A              B                                         
0     US1           URL1                                                                                              
1     US2           URL1                                                                                              
2     US1           URL2
3     US3           URL3
4     US2           URL3
4     US2           URL3
```

I'd like to obtain a dataframe in which for each unique element in B the  count of the unique elements in B and the number of unique element in A associated with b:

```
         B            Imp      Aud                                       
0     URL1              2        2                                                                                            
1     URL2              1        1                                                                                          
2     URL3              3        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby.agg`; with [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) to get the number of elements and [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) to get the number of unique elements:

```
df.groupby('B', as_index=False).A.agg({'Imp': 'size', 'Aud': 'nunique'})

#      B    Imp   Aud
#0  URL1      2     2
#1  URL2      1     1
#2  URL3      3     2
```

Comment: Thank you @Psidom !